The task is not canceled after a specified period of time
I have a С# web api application that accepts requests (from a website, for example) to solve mathematical problems. Since solving such problems can take a very long time, i use a separate console application for them, which is launched from the Web api, and transfer data via the clipboard. In addition, i set the timeout (via CancellationToken) and, if the console application does not have time to complete its work, i forcibly terminate it using the Kill function.
Here is the code:
// create an instance of the Process object:
using Process prs = new Process();

// fill data:
prs.StartInfo.FileName = processPath;
prs.StartInfo.Arguments = inputJson;
prs.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
prs.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

// start console app which solves math:
prs.Start();

// save moment of time when app start working:
DateTime processStartTime = DateTime.Now;

// create obje - create cancellation token every 15 seconds:
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
CancellationToken tenSecondsToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

// asynchronously read data from the stream:
Task<string> result = prs.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync(tenSecondsToken);

try
{
    // wait for 10 seconds for console app to finish:
    await prs.WaitForExitAsync(tenSecondsToken);

    // if we got here - its success!
    // calculate how long it took to complete the application:
    TimeSpan spentTime = DateTime.Now - processStartTime;

    // return the result:
    return result.Result;
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // here, the console application did not have time to shut down in 10 seconds,
    // and WaitForExitAsync throws an exception:
    TimeSpan spentTimeForApplication = DateTime.Now - processStartTime;

    // save moment in time before we started "killing" the process:
    DateTime processKillStartTime = DateTime.Now;

    // kill console app and all its child processes:
    prs.Kill(true);

    // time to spent to terminate the process:
    TimeSpan timeToKill = DateTime.Now - processKillStartTime;

    // возвращаем результат:
    return string.Empty;
}

I use seq for logging.
Seq for loggin
The WaitForExitAsync function worked for 2 minutes (from 09:30:47.949 to 09:32:50.084) instead of 10 seconds.
The console application ran for almost 8 minutes (from 09:32:50.084 to 09:40:14.533).
Question: Why CancellationToken does not always fire after a set period of time, and the Kill console application may take a long time? What could be the reason?
Or maybe there is some better solution to perform and stop long-running tasks?
I didn't find the answer in internet. Can anybody help me?

I have a guess that the hang is caused by waiting for the process of reading the output streams as standard. and a stream of errors. I implemented a similar bundle for breaking technology stacks, but in my implementation I specified the result path in the application launch parameters. I didn't output the result to the console. This is a more reliable way. since you can save data in json, and store abstractions for data serialization/deserialization in a separate assembly

A Task should always be awaited.

I didn't quite understand, did you save the result of the console application to a file or how did you transfer the result of the console application to the web api?

Since solving such problems can take a very long time, i use a separate console application for them, which is launched from the Web api, - why? That's kinda daft because it robs you of nearly all your control of the process. Instead make the code that solves the problem an async code  inside the API project and pass the token to it. Have it pass the token on to any async code it uses etc etc then when the timer runs out, it will abort itself. Return a different status code maybe. Don't return a 408 btw as the client may retry it automatically

I can't do it. To solve math i use library which doesn't support cancellation token and not async...

You should ask for help with that. If it's just computation you can Task.Run it

I don't really like the following solution, it looks unreasonably cumbersome, but I came to it because the standard call to Process.WaitForExitAsync(CancellationToken) with a token was not canceled when the timeout was triggered. That is, my main thread in which I launch the process froze.
Initially I thought the problem was in the external process, but I wrote a simple console application with Thread.Sleep(time) in which the timeout was greater than the timeout in the main code. In the main code, the current did not work and did not complete the process, as I expected. That's why this solution came up. In it, we wait for the process in a separate thread, which simply runs in the background. In the main thread (assuming it is a Task), we suspend it while waiting using ManualResetEvent. In this solution there is no specific implementation of reading the process output, because there are 2 scenarios - implementing events for the appearance of data in the output or redirecting the outputs and reading them after the process ends. In my case, this code works exactly as I need - either the process ends successfully or is killed after 5 minutes (the time is abstract, but it is several times longer than the time of the slowest execution).
//Creating 
using var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, arguments)
{
    WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
    //You should decide how will you read data from outpus
    //RedirectStandardError = true,
    //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

using var manualEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var waitTime = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(waitTime);
try
{
    //Starting process...
    if (!process.Start())
    {
        //Process wasn't started
        return false;
    }

    //Process started
    using var t = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        //Waiting process executed
        await process.WaitForExitAsync();
        manualEvent.Set();
    }).ContinueWith((e) =>
    {
        if(e.Exception != null)
        {
            //write to log exception
        }
    }).WaitAsync(cts.Token);

    var wait = manualEvent.WaitOne(waitTime);

    if (!wait)
    {
        process.Kill();
        //Process killed after wainting for 5 minutes
        //probably you should call [WaitForExit][1], but sometime it redundrant
        //if you killed process, there is no resone to read any process outputs
    }
    
    if (!t.IsCompleted)
    {
        //Process stuck on killing?, cancel token...
        cts.Cancel(true);
        // waiting for task complete to avoid exception from it on dispose, time to wait can be redused
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    //If you redirected outputs, and process wasn't killed, here you reading them
    return process.ExitCode == 0;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //write to log exception
    return false;
}
finally
{
    //process ends
}

I found similar questions on stackoverflow regarding process freezing. They advised to redirect process output streams and be sure to read them at the end of termination. But in my case, the process started, appeared in the task manager, but was not actually executed, either with or without redirecting output streams. The biggest problem for me was that the freeze only happened on some computers, while on most everything worked fine.
